# How to get response from other file request response in Laravue

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, request, http-post

I'm trying to get the response from File2.vue and pass back to File1.vue. I'm using VueJS v1.0.28, How to get response from other file request response?

**File1.vue**

```
   File2.updateNotice(this,{'id':id}).then((response) => {
      console.log("response from File2  :",response)
   });
```

**File2.vue**

```
updateNotice(context,params) {
            let url = staff_service.STAFF_NOTICES_READ_RESOURCE;
            Vue.http.post(
                url,
                params
            ).then(response => {
                return response;
            }) 
}
```

Error response from File1:

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: What is your question? Please be clear. You have already consoled your response.

Comment: I want to get the response from File2.vue and pass back to File1.vue.

Comment: You can use vuex, pass the response to state. In `file1.vue` check for state change and get the value in `file.vue`

Comment: You need to put a return before `Vue.http.post` to return the promise to the caller - otherwise, you're returning nothing from `updateNotice` hence `then` is undefined

Comment: @steve16351 OH MY !"#$%&'(!!!!! My bad, thanks! I was able now get the response forgot to put some return statement. Save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

*This is now solved, added a*

> return

*before*

> Vue.http.post(

*in **File2.vue***

**File1.vue**

```
   File2.updateNotice(this,{'id':id}).then((response) => {
      console.log("response from File2  :",response)
   });
```

**File2.vue**

```
updateNotice(context,params) {
            let url = staff_service.STAFF_NOTICES_READ_RESOURCE;
            return Vue.http.post(
                url,
                params
            ).then(response => {
                return response;
            }) 
}
```